# AWS Batch: How to check if requested fargate resources match what's provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I have a job definition in AWS Batch for a job to be run on `Fargate` Spot. The definition defines among other things the required `VCPU` and `MEMORY` values for the task.

Here's an example how it looks like in cloudformation:

```yaml
ResourceRequirements:
  -
    Type: VCPU
    Value: 2
  -
    Type: MEMORY
    Value: 4096
```

and in the console:

[image]

So far so good. When I submit a task with this definition, a Fargate container gets spun up in ECS. But there's no indication as to what resources this container has.

The relevant details in the running ECS task are empty/not-defined:

[image]

and the script I'm running gives an indication that there's more memory available than requested.

So how can I (in the most easy way) confirm that the requested resources for this task is what's being provided?

My concern is that once the processing scales up, over-provided resources would mean significant excess cost.

Comment: Does does not seem as even a valid setup. For 4 CPUs you need at least 8192 RAM.

Comment: thanks @Marcin - copy & paste error!